# Error when running a Flutter Android template project: 'The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to Flutter development, so please bear with me if this is a basic question. I'm trying to run a [Flutter Android template project](https://github.com/mathebuddy/mathebuddy), and I've encountered an error that I'm having trouble resolving. I believe this issue might be easy to identify for experienced Flutter developers, so I'll provide the relevant error message without sharing my entire codebase.

Here's the error I'm encountering:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/color.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/mbcl/src/level_item.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:mathebuddy/mbcl/src/level_item.dart';
       ^
```

I've stored all the project files and directories on my PC's D drive, while Android Studio is installed on the C drive. I'm wondering if this configuration might be causing the issue, but I'm not entirely sure.

Could someone please help me identify the problem and suggest a solution? If the drive configuration is indeed the problem, I'd appreciate guidance on how to address it. Thank you!

I've already confirmed that the Dart files mentioned in the error message are present in the directory structure exactly as specified. However, I'm not sure if the issue lies in the drive configuration, as my project files are on my PC's D drive, while Android Studio is on the C drive.

I'm hoping to identify the root cause of this error and find a solution to it. If necessary, I'm prepared to provide screenshots of the relevant directory contents to assist with troubleshooting.

Comment: Are you sure that `level_item.dart` exists in your project?

Comment: yes, it is there. at D:\Projects\flutter\mathebuddy\lib\mbcl\src

Comment: I have two locations where there are dart files, one in the ~\lib\mbcl\src where there are only 6 dart files, while at ~\app\lib contains 29 dart files. The files at the first location are chapter.dart
course.dart
event.dart
Ievel.dart
level_item.dart
unit.dart